# Multi-targeting a project to enable both 4.5 and 5 versions of .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.5, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm experimenting with VS2015 to create some sort of unified dev framework.

The whole ideia is to unify code into a single project that targets .net 4.5, aspnet50 and aspnet50core (whenever possible).

One of the base interfaces should define:

- System.Data.IDbConnection for .NET 4.5
- System.Data.Common.DbConnection for AspNet 5

it's as bellow:

```
public interface
{
#if ASPNET50
    System.Data.Common.DbConnection GetConnection();
#endif

#if NET45
    System.Data.IDbConnection GetConnection();
#endif
}
```

I've updated `project.json` to be like:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net45": {
        "dependencies": {
        }
    }
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Data.SqlClient": "1.0.0-beta2"
        }
    }
}
```

Only option I have is to reference `System.Data.Common` into .net 4.5 `dependencies` (but won't work since it's not built to support .net 4.5).

If I try to reference `"System.Data": "4.0.0.0"` or even without the version number, VS2015 can't resolve to gac and won't recognize the reference.

Any hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly you'll see something like the following setup:

- [Solution]

  - [Project1]

    - [Properties]
    - Project1.NET45.csproj
    - Project1.ASPNET5.csproj
    - Class1.cs

Within each project you define a symbol (e.g. `ASPNET5`, `NET45`). Then each will have references to assemblies that matter for that build. Also, you can then include common files in both projects (and in these files use symbols found in each project to differentiate code), but you can also break out implementations for version-specific features (e.g. Class1.NET45.cs which is only included in the NET45 project)

Comment: Not sure on how will that fit into a Asp.Net 5 project, if it will at all. The problem is that VS changed the whole way it works with Asp.Net 5 (vNext) projects.

Comment: @ALMMa - as of CTP5 (just released) it can now work with standard .csproj files as well I believe

Comment: It's supported VS for a while now... [vNext on VS2014](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/06/asp-net-vnext-in-visual-studio-14-ctp-4.aspx) (that was CTP4).

Comment: @BradChristie, that did the trick actually. A lot more complex than simply add corresponding csproj files because a kproj (vnext) project works completely diferent. But with some extra work it became possible just fine. Now, hands on to make that fit into a nuget package =) Thanks!

Comment: @BradChristie after some testing, changing "net45" to "net451" or "net452" worked from within the "vNext" project without the need to create separate `csproj` files and all. Since we currently use .net 4.5.1 I think it will be the best approach for our framework =)